# Position navbar icons inline on mobile with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to configure a navbar in Bootstrap 4 to display additional icons to left the hamburger menu that only display on mobile.

I'm not able to get the icons to display inline and can't sort out where i am going wrong.

I add the classes navbar-nav to the list, d-lg-none to hide on larger devices. Are there built in classes in bootstrap that can fix the alignment of these? I can't even sort out where i am going wrong.

[image: Broken Navbar]

HTML:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="assets/images/logo-blue-sm.png" alt="">
                </a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav d-lg-none ml-auto navbar-icons ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="tel:+1234567890"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-map-marker"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="tel:+1234567890"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-comments"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">                 
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="docMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Experience</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="docMenu">
                                <li> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Story</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item border-0 d-none d-lg-inline-block align-self-center">
                    <a href="#" class=" btn btn-sm btn-grad text-white mb-0">Get Started</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Additional CSS:

```
.navbar-icons .nav-item{
  border-bottom:none;
  padding:0 5px;
  position:relative;
 }
```

Comment: have you tried adding `d-flex` and  `flex-row` classes to the ul that contains the list items with your icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your layout you could easily solve that using bootstrap flex utility classes [Read more](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

Just add `d-flex` and `flex-row` classes to the `ul` that contains the items:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav d-lg-none ml-auto navbar-icons d-flex flex-row">
```

this will change the `ul`s display to flex and force the flex direction to be row style, so the items will be displayed side by side.

here is a very good guide to [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). try understanding the basics and using it together with the bootstrap flex classes.

Comment: Thanks that did it, article on flexbox was helpful. Transitioning from BS3 to 4 so a bit of a learning curve!